# What is the etiquette in python for access "private" attributes of another instance of the same class?

Tags: python, private, private-members

I know that in python there are no formal ways to introduce private attributes of a class, and usually you just denote something private by prepending an underscore `_`.

I have a class that looks like below:

```
class my_class:
  def __init__(self):
    self._attr1 = # some initialization
  def method_that_merges_another_class_instance(self, other):
    # I want to access other's _attr1 attribute in here even though it's private.
```

Is it acceptable to directly access `_attr1` from other within `method_that_merges_another_class_instance`?

Comment: Possibly related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1301369/1016514